# Contour integral of inverse square root.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

I want to calculate the below complex integral on the upper-semi-circle which its radius goes to infinity:

$$ \oint \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$$

I tried with the substitution $z = R e^{i \theta}$ where $0<\theta<\pi$, and then took the limit where $R$ goes to infinity, but I counldn't find sensible result.  Is it due to the fact that my substitution crosses the branch cut? (Either the cut taken from $i$ to infinity or to connect $-i$ and $i$.) If this is the case, how can one evaluate this integral, by the way if it converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Idea:*

Note that for large $R$ we have that $\sqrt{1+z^2} \approx z$. This result is analytic without any branch cut. So it is useful for integration.

*Formal:*

We have to branch points of $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ at $z=\pm i$. We may choose the branch cut **between** between these branch points. With this choice, we have that (for $|z| > 1$)
$$ \sqrt{ 1+z^2} = z \sqrt{1+1/z^2}$$
where on the right hand side the branch cut does not play a role [as $\operatorname{Re}(1+1/z^2)>0$].
With that we have for the upper semi-circle ($z= R e^{i\theta}$)
$$\int  \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = \int  \frac{dz}{z \sqrt{1+1/z^2}}  = i \int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta + O(1/R) \to \pi i \quad (R\to \infty).$$

To this, we add the contribution of the integral along the real line. For this we obtain 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\pm\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ 
where the sign $+$ has to be chosen for $x>0$ and $-$ for $x<0$ (given that the branch cut is between $+i$ and $-i$). Due to the fact that we integrate an odd function, this part of the contour vanishes and we have that
$$\oint \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = i \pi\;.$$

Comment: Thanks. If we choose the branch cut between $\pm i$, how can we also add the contribution of the contour integral on the bottom (horizontal) line of the semi-circle? (It crosses the cut.)

Comment: Oh, I thought that you want to integrate only over the semi-circle (without the part along the real line). If you include the part of the real line, the integral still is not closed as you necessarily end up in the second Riemann sheet (by having encircled a branch point). In this case, the result of course depends on the branch cuts chosen. So you should specify in which branch cut you are interested. (initially I wrote the answer for the complete circle at $R \to \infty$ in which case the branch cut does not matter)

Comment: The branch cut as you have already chosen. Another question: How can one make this integral closed? That is, if we start from $- \infty$ on the real axis, then move on and encircle the branch point $i$ and continue and move on the semi-circle, we don't come back to our initial point, indeed we are on the second sheet. How can we make it closed, that is: coming back to our initial point?

Comment: You can encircle the branch point (at $z=+i$) a second time. Another choice would be to encircle the other branch point (at $z=-i$) in the opposite direction.

Comment: Now that the final result is $i \pi$, can one say that if we encircle the branch point $+ i$ for a second time in order to end up in our starting point, the result becomes $2 i \pi$?

Comment: @Simple: no, the second time, you are on the second branch. So the integrand is minus the integrand in the first case. So encircling the branch point again, leads to $-i\pi$ and thus  the total result is 0.